# CORS plugin chrome in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm making cross origin ajax requests using jquery and I wanted to set headers in the request like this-- but it says that it is an improper request:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: address,
        headers:{
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
         }
        success: function(result) {
            pipelineCallback(result, guid_key, j, missing_program);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        async: true
    });
```

Caveat: When I don't set the header and use this CORS chrome plugin the cross-origin request goes through fine... whats the issue?

Plugin link(theres a public github repo too):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: If it works, why would you want to add the header anyways?

Comment: You need to set the server to use the header.

Comment: The server does use the header-- I'm saying I don't want to use the plugin to set the header on the request. I want to set the header manually on the request.

Answer (score 4):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a request header.

The CORS browser plugin **fakes** adding it to the response.

Adding a non-standard header to a **request** triggers [a preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) which requires a specific kind of response to tell the browser that it is OK to make the request with the non-standard header.

Adding `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the response (which is what the browser plugin does) is not sufficient to grant that permission. (Preflighted requests require an explicit allowed origin in the response, not a wild card).

Comment: So can I fake this without using the plugin in jquery?

Comment: @KonradS — No. That would render the entire security feature pointless. The other server has to give your site permission to use the browser's credentials to read data from it. You can't give yourself permission (although the owner of the browser can, as you have discovered with the plugin, hack the *browser* to disable the check).